# Tracking upload progress

Tags: php, upload, progress

I want to track the upload progress of a file to my server so I read this [(German) article](http://www.it-gecko.de/php-5-4-datei-upload-mit-fortschrittsanzeige-progressbar.html). I already checked my PHP.ini:

```
session.upload_progress.enabled = 1
session.upload_progress.cleanup = 1
session.upload_progress.prefix = upload_progress_
session.upload_progress.name = PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
session.upload_progress.freq = 1%
session.upload_progress.min_freq = 1
upload_max_filesize = 128M
```

I began to write a very simple script that only shows a form and uploads a file, when submitted:

```
<!-- upload.php -->
<?php
    session_start();

    $maxSize = 10485760;
    $uploadName = "test";

    if (@$_POST["upload"] ?: 0) { // Check, if upload is in progress
        $t = getcwd() . "\\" . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

        if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > $maxSize) {
            echo "Upload " . (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $t) ? "succeeded" : "failed"); // Return, if upload is succeeded or failed
        }
    } else {
        ?>
            <form action="<?= basename(__FILE__); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="frmUpload" method="POST" target="upload">
                <input name="file" type="file" />
                <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
                <input name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" type="hidden" value="<?= $maxSize; ?>" />
                <input name="upload" type="hidden" value="1" />
                <input name="<?= ini_get("session.upload_progress.name"); ?>" type="hidden" value="<?= $uploadName; ?>" /> <!-- Set session name -->
            </form>
            <div style="display: none; ">
                <iframe id="upload"></iframe>
            </div>
        <?php
    }
?>
```

My second script should check the upload progress with the session name

```
// uploadProgress.php
<?php
    session_start();
    $pName = ini_get("session.upload_progress.prefix") . "test";
    echo json_encode(@$_SESSION[$pName] ?: []);
?>
```

I created a 10mb file, to ensure a long upload time. Everytime I call uploadProgress.php while the upload is running `$_SESSION[$pName]` is not set and I cannot find my mistake. Is there something I overlooked or something I made wrong?

Comment: the field which sets the session name has to be before the file input field in the form

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me as I'm not used to the syntax you're using... Not sure why you're using ternary operators in your `IF` statements, or why you're suppressing the `$_SESSION` and `$_POST` variables.

The only thing that stands out to me in your examples is I don't see any call to `session_start()`?

Here is [another article](http://www.sitepoint.com/tracking-upload-progress-with-php-and-javascript/) that may help.

Comment: I supress the `$_SESSION`, because I don't like the error message "NOTICE..." and I use ternary operators to give the `$_SESSION` and `$POST` a "default" value. I know, I don't have to do this, but it was a simple test file. But thanks for your help :)

Comment: When I don't use `session_start();`, `$_SESSION` doesn't exist. When I use it, `$_SESSION` is always empty.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem. Found a way to track the progress with JavaScript. Here is my solution:

```
/**********************\
| Script of upload.php |
\**********************/
var ui = { elems: ["dUploads", "fFile", "frmUpload", "pbPercent", "pbUpload", "pbWrpUpload"] }; for (var n = 0; n < ui.elems.length; n++) { ui[ui.elems[n]] = document.getElementById(ui.elems[n]); } delete ui.elems;

function refreshUploads (files) {
    var tmp;
    while (tmp = dUploads.firstChild) {
        tmp.remove();
    }

    for (var file in files) {
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.setAttribute("href", "uploads/" + files[file]);
        a.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
        a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(files[file]));

        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.appendChild(a);

        ui.dUploads.appendChild(div);
    }
}

ui.frmUpload.onsubmit = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var data = new FormData();

    data.append("ajax", 1);
    data.append("file", ui.fFile.files[0]);

    ajax.upload.onprogress = function (e) {
        var percent = Math.floor(e.loaded / e.total * 100) + "%";
        ui.pbUpload.style.left = percent;
        ui.pbPercent.style.left = percent;
        ui.pbPercent.innerHTML = percent;
    };

    ajax.onreadystatechange = function (e) {
        if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
            ui.pbWrpUpload.style.opacity = "0";
            refreshUploads(eval(ajax.responseText));
        }
    };

    ui.pbWrpUpload.style.opacity = "1";

    ajax.open("POST", "upload.php", true);
    ajax.send(data);
};

refreshUploads([]); // Normally all already existing files are loaded via PHP
```